# Print a multiplication table in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

How to print a multiplication table in python in which the number must be defined by the user and print the table up to a maximum of 20 rows. Even if the number of rows asked by the user is more than 20, we should limit up to 20 rows and print an error message saying "rows is limited to 20"

Take input from the user in which-

- x is a positive integer
- y is a non negative integer

## **Sample Input and Output 1**

```
6 * 1 = 6
6 * 2 = 12
6 * 3 = 18
6 * 4 = 24
6 * 5 = 30
6 * 6 = 36
6 * 7 = 42
6 * 8 = 48
6 * 9 = 54
6 * 10 = 60
6 * 11 = 66
6 * 12 = 72
6 * 13 = 78
6 * 14 = 84
6 * 15 = 90
6 * 16 = 96
6 * 17 = 102
6 * 18 = 108
```

## **Sample Input and Output 2**

```
Enter the number for the multiplication table: 9
Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: 25
9 * 1 = 9
9 * 2 = 18
9 * 3 = 27
9 * 4 = 36
9 * 5 = 45
9 * 6 = 54
9 * 7 = 63
9 * 8 = 72
9 * 9 = 81
9 * 10 = 90
9 * 11 = 99
9 * 12 = 108
9 * 13 = 117
9 * 14 = 126
9 * 15 = 135
9 * 16 = 144
9 * 17 = 153
9 * 18 = 162
9 * 19 = 171
9 * 20 = 180
rows is limited to 20
```

## **My Code**

```
x = int(input("Enter the number for the multiplication table: "))
y = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: "))

for i in range(1, y + 1):
    result = x * i
    print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
else:
    if y > 20:
        print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
```

## **But My Output**

```
Enter the number for the multiplication table: 9
Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: 25
9 * 1 = 9
9 * 2 = 18
9 * 3 = 27
9 * 4 = 36
9 * 5 = 45
9 * 6 = 54
9 * 7 = 63
9 * 8 = 72
9 * 9 = 81
9 * 10 = 90
9 * 11 = 99
9 * 12 = 108
9 * 13 = 117
9 * 14 = 126
9 * 15 = 135
9 * 16 = 144
9 * 17 = 153
9 * 18 = 162
9 * 19 = 171
9 * 20 = 180
9 * 21 = 189
9 * 22 = 198
9 * 23 = 207
9 * 24 = 216
9 * 25 = 225
rows is limited to 20
```

***I want to remove the extra lines after 9 * 20 = 180 and display the error message.***
(Please keep the for loop and the else statement)

Comment: Can't you set the range end to just `min(20, y)+1`? That way it never exceeds 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the requirement of using for loop and else statement, you can add a conditional statement inside the loop and use it to break the loop when the condition is met. Here's the modified code:

```
x = int(input("Enter the number for the multiplication table: "))
y = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: "))

for i in range(1, y + 1):
    result = x * i
    print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
    if i >= 20:
        print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
        break
else:
    if y > 20:
        print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach:

```
x = int(input("Enter the number for the multiplication table: "))
y = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: "))
if y > 20:
 print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
 y=20

for i in range(1, y + 1):
 result = x * i
 print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
```

This way, the user gets a return message about the limitation beforehand.

The bit more advanced version would be, just as @B Remmelzwaal suggested:

```
x = int(input("Enter the number for the multiplication table: "))
y = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: "))

for i in range(1, min(y,20) + 1):
 result = x * i
 print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
else:
 if y > 20:
  print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is a simpler way to do this, I get you are doing this for learning purposes so let me suggest a fix without altering your code too much.
What you must always remember is to **check the conditions before producing the output.** What you are doing above is producing the output first before checking whether the value for columns in this case *y is greater than 20.*
Here is the actual code that works for your case

```
x = int(input("Enter the number for the multiplication table: "))
y = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the multiplication table: "))
#check to see if y exceeds 20 and if so, cap it at 20
if y > 20:
    print("The number of rows is limited to 20") 
    y = 20
for i in range(1, y + 1):
    result = x * i
    print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong `for` loop command: you are using the `for`with an `else` clause, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). The `else` block will be executed when the iterator will become empty

```
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
else:
    print('done!')
#0
#1
#done!
```

but what you need is an indented block

```
for i in range(1, y + 1):
    if i > 20:
       print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
       break
    result = x * i
    print(f"{x} * {i} = {result}")
```

or just change the upper bound of the `range` with

```
y = (y if y<=20 else 20)
for i in range(1, y + 1):
   ...
print("The number of rows has been limited to 20.")
```